# How send data to Firefox extension from external application

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

We have developed extension addon-sdk with js-ctypes.

Is there anything in firefox what can get some data from external application.
May be need use this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/test_httpd ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a bunch of possibilities... E.g.

- Sockets via [`nsISocketTransport`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/base/public/nsISocketTransportService.idl) and/or [`nsIServerSocket`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/base/public/nsIServerSocket.idl).
- HTTP via regular `XHR` and/or [`nsIHttpServer`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/test/httpserver/nsIHttpServer.idl) (you kinda already found that one).
- Lower-level OS APIs via [`js-ctypes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes).

Comment: Thank you, save electricity for googling!

Comment: I know some extensions actually use websockets as this is a simpler high-level api for socket communications.